# Cartesian product of a set containing all real numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, relations

Let S be the set of all sequences of real numbers. Let R be the relation

$R = \{(a, b) \in S \times S  |  a_3 = b_3\}$

I'm trying to find out whether R satisfies the properties reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric, and symmetric. Isn't the Cartesian product $ S \times S$, where $S$ is the set containing all sequences of real numbers, going to be infinite? Furthermore, this relation must satisfy reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity, correct? Every real number would be paired with every other real number, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $S\times S$ is the set of all ordered pairs of sequences of real numbers; it is indeed infinite, since $S$ is. The relation $R$ has all but one of the properties of reflexivity, transitivity, antisymmetry, and symmetry, but this has nothing to do with pairing real numbers: members of $R$ are pairs of *sequences* of real numbers, not pairs of real numbers.

If $a=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $b=\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are two sequences of real numbers, the pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ is in $R$ if and only if $a_3=b_3$. For example, if $a$ is the constant sequence defined by $a_n=3$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, and $b$ is the sequence defined by $b_n=n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then $\langle a,b\rangle=R$, because $a_3=b_3=3$.

- **Reflexivity:** If $a=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of real numbers, is it true that $a_3=a_3$? If this is always the case, then $\langle a,a\rangle\in R$ for each $a\in S$, and $R$ is therefore reflexive. If there is even one sequence in $S$ for which it’s not true, then $R$ is not reflexive.
- **Symmetry:** If $a=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $b=\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are sequences of real numbers, and $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$, is it always true that $\langle b,a\rangle\in R$? In other words, if $a_3=b_3$, is it always true that $b_3=a_3$?
- **Transitivity:** If $a=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, $b=\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and $c=\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are sequences of real numbers, $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$, and $\langle b,c\rangle\in R$, is it always true that $\langle a,c\rangle\in R$? Use the definition of $R$ as I did in the first two parts to translate this question into a more basic one.
- **Antisymmetry:** If $a=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $b=\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are sequences of real numbers, $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$, and $\langle b,a\rangle\in R$, is it always true that $a=b$? Again, use the definition of $R$ as I did in the first two parts to translate this question into a more basic one.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking about the problem like this: the condition that the number at $a_3 = b_3$ just says that the two numbers at $a_3$ and $b_3$ must be equal for those sequences, correct? In that case, then $a_2 neq b_2$ is possible, right?

Comment: @GBR24: Yes; in fact, that’s the case in the example that I gave, in which $a_2=3$ but $b_2=2$.

Comment: To be sure I'm on the right path, here, are all of the conditions satisfied, except for antisymmetry?

Comment: @GBR24: Yes, that’s correct.